# Android Studio ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, neuroph

After importing external libs to my project every time I run project i get ClassNotFoundException:

```
06-09 18:22:49.759 12976-13005/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: dataLoader
Process: prm.soundpaint, PID: 12976
org.neuroph.core.exceptions.NeurophException: Class not found while trying to read neural network from file!
    at org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork.load(NeuralNetwork.java:638)
    at prm.soundpaint.DrawingView$1.run(DrawingView.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2263)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1641)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1782)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1113)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:454)
    at org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork.readObject(NeuralNetwork.java:651)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1330)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1835)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
    at org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork.load(NeuralNetwork.java:631)
    at prm.soundpaint.DrawingView$1.run(DrawingView.java:60) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/prm.soundpaint-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2263) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1641) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1782) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1113) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:454) 
    at org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork.readObject(NeuralNetwork.java:651) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1330) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1242) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1835) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940) 
    at org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork.load(NeuralNetwork.java:631) 
    at prm.soundpaint.DrawingView$1.run(DrawingView.java:60) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 24 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

JARs are inside 'libs' folder:
[libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQmT2.jpg)

I also added dependencies to build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "prm.soundpaint"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/neuroph-core-2.94.jar')
    implementation files('libs/neuroph-imgrec-2.94.jar')
    implementation files('libs/neuroph-ocr-2.94.jar')
}
```

It crashes in the line where object is initialized:

```
private Runnable loadDataRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        InputStream irs = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.m1);
        nnet = NeuralNetwork.load(irs);
    }
};
```

I tried to solve this problem by diasabling instant run in android studio but with no effect. I also tried to:

- delete build folder, clean and rebuild project
- invalidate caches and restart
- restart device
- enable multiDex in build.gradle and in Manifest file:

  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
  multiDexEnabled true
  android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
- disable preDexLibraries by dexOptions {
  preDexLibraries false
  }

**EDIT**
[Screenshot of project workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmxrX.jpg)

Unfortunately application still crashes on  every run. I have device with Android 5. Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: I updated post with screenshot. 2.94 is the latest release of this libs. http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/download.html

Comment: Multidex won't discover classes that aren't there. Don't use JAR files... Delete them. Add `implementation 'org.neuroph:neuroph-core:2.94'`

Comment: Also, keep in mind that not all Java libraries can be used by Android. The second error is  `ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic` because Logback is not used in Android